# Zend equivelant of YII Widgets?

Tags: php, zend-framework, yii

In YII you can easily create a widget that you can call on a view:

```
$this->widget(....)
```

What is the equivelant of this in Zend? I want to be able to create a "widget" that displays a special type of table that works just by passing data to it.

Comment: There is no "Widget" implementation in Zend Framework. You could use View Helpers or Action Helpersfor this task. Have a look at this blog post: http://www.mwop.net/blog/246-Using-Action-Helpers-To-Implement-Re-Usable-Widgets.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Zend View Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html). You create class with predefined signature, and then use it in view. Example view helper class:

```
class Zend_View_Helper_Hello
{
    // Notice: function name is same as last class name part
    public function hello($name)
    {
        // Code here
        return sprintf('Hello %s!', $name);
    }
}
```

Then in your view:

```
echo $this->hello('John');
```